# Where to implement a protocol using boost::asio?

Tags: c++, protocols, boost-asio

I am trying to implement a simple serial port protocol. It goes like this:

1. discard all data until `0xff` is received
2. read header (node address and data length, 4 bytes)
3. read data (max. 64 bytes)
4. read crc
5. process the received packet
6. send response
7. when `0xff` is seen, even when not expected like in the middle of the data, it means a new packet is received

I can implement this using `boost::asio::serial_port` with `boost::asio::read()` reading a single byte and processing this byte when it is received. Although this works, I was wondering if there is a more 'boost' like way to do this?

I looked at `boost::asio::read_until()` for reading until `0xff`, but then I don't know how to discard the data. Storing the data in a buffer and then not using the buffer seems a bit wasteful.

I can use `boost::asio::read_until()` for reading until the end of the packet but then the `MatchCondition` needs to have access to (the header of the packet in) the buffer. It seems the `MatchCondition` only gets an iterator to the first and last byte recently received.

Also, the data received using `boost::asio::read()` ends up in a `stream_buf` and I have to parse the received data into a `Packet` object. I can do this parsing inside `Packet`, in a separate `ParsePacket` object or somehow integrate it with `boost::asio` (something like `boost::asio::read(serial, myPacket);` where `myPacket` is a `Packet` object)

When `0xff` is seen anywhere in the received data, it means a new packet is starting. So when `0xff` is received, it must forget any previous received data and start receiving a new packet.

I am planning on using asynchronous operations and adding timeouts.

So, my question is: where to implement a protocol like this? Or more generally, where to implement a protocol using `boost::asio`. I am not looking for working code but something like advise on where to implement the protocol and which `boost::asio` functionality to use.

update:

There is no flow control (hardware or software) used in this case.

Comment: A comment on your protocol: what if the crc calculates to be `0xff`?

Comment: @Autopulated: crc can never be `0xff`, also the data and the headers never contain `0xff`. `0xff` is reserved for the beginning of a new packet.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as @Autopulated pointed in comments, I want to warn you about using delimiters (your 0xFF) in binary protocols. It's dangerous technique (brings a lot of ambiguity) and requires complicated implementations. Even if you can guarantee that your data doesn't contain 0xFF bytes you cannot do this about CRC field.

I would recommend to not bother with any delimiters and concentrate on simple and predictable binary protocol: `[packet][packet]...` where `[packet] = [node address:X][data length:4][data:data length][CRC:1]`

Sending such packets can look like:

```
size_t const data_length_bytes = 4;

std::vector<char> data = ...;
size_t data_length = data.size();
Node_address node_address = ...;

std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> bufs;
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&node_address, sizeof(node_address)));
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data_length, data_length_bytes));
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(data));

boost::system::error_code error;
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(bufs), error);
if (error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error);
```

Receiving:

```
size_t data_length;
std::vector<char> data;
Node_address node_address;
char crc;

std::vector<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> bufs;
boost::system::error_code error;

bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&node_address, sizeof(node_address)));
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data_length, data_length_bytes));
boost::asio::read(serial_port, bufs, error);
if (error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error);

data.resize(data_length);
bufs.clear();
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data.front(), data_length));
bufs.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&crc, sizeof(crc));
boost::asio::read(serial_port, bufs, error);
if (error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error);

// check CRC
// send response
```

Please note that this example makes assumption that both peers has the same endianess.

I wrote this code here so don't expect it's correct, use it just as an idea.

Comment: The crc used is crc-7 with the highest bit always 0 so the crc byte can not be 0xff

Comment: There needs to be some magic value signalling the beginning of a new packet. If there isn't then how would you detect the beginning of a new packet? If the program is started then there is no guarantee the first byte received is the beginning of a new packet. (there is no flowcontrol used)

Comment: Other than that, you example is quite useful, but I am not sure if it will work with a delimiter.

Comment: You can put that magic byte at the beginning of the packet and add its reading/writing to the port. At the beginning of receiving `read_until` magic byte is received (you need to store this data and discard it, nothing to do with this). When you synchronized your stream, you don't need to check for magic byte any more.

Comment: of course, I was trying to make it too fool proof. Like how to handle the situation when something goes wrong and there is an 0xff in the middle of the data.

Comment: The standard procedure for dealing with this is escaping. Say you have three special characters: start packet `STX='('`, end packet `ETX=')'` and escape `DLE='\'`. Just replace any occurence of any of the three special characters `x` inside the packet by `DLE+x`.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing protocols, I have previously found state-machines very useful.

Whilst I haven't used `asio`, this technique may be applicable here.

These can be implemented in C++ as an `enum`, a loop and a `switch` as follows:

```
enum States { StateInitial, StateHeader, StateData ... };

States state = StateInitial;
while (1)
{
    char ch = get_byte_function();
    switch (state)
    {
        case StateInitial:
            if (ch == '\xFF')
                state = StateHeader;
            break;

        case StateHeader:
            ...
    }
}
```

You would need to add more flags to keep track of your progress within the protocol.

You may also want to look at [`boost::statechart`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html) for implementing the state machine.

Comment: Yes, this is my initial solution also. However I was wondering if there is a better solution using boost::asio besides reading a single byte and then processing it. I am more interested in how to integrate this nicely with boost::asio.

Comment: Maybe your question could have said what methods you had already looked at using then.